# Send Mail using Java Mail

Tags: java, jsp, smtp

Hell Guys!
I want  to send an email using jee. That's the code i used, but it's not working. The code i used is below.

index.html 
         `
          
        
         Java Mail

```
                <thead><tr> <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <b> Send Mail </b> </td> </tr> </thead>
                <tr> <td> To </td> <td> : </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="to" value="" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Subject </td> <td> : </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="subject" value="" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Message </td> <td> : </td>
                    <td> <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="30">
                    </textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" />

                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                    <td>
                </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

`

i created a bean that contains sender's email id and password and receiver's email id
Mail.java
     `package jMail;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Mail {

      private String to;
      private String from;
      private String message;
      private String subject;
      private String smtpServ;
      public int sendMail(){
    try
    {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();


         props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp" );
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true" );
          props.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpServ);
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true" );
          Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
          // -- Create a new message --
          Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
          msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,    InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
          msg.setSubject(subject);
          msg.setText(message);
          // -- Set some other header information --
          msg.setHeader("MyMail", "Mr. XYZ" );
          msg.setSentDate(new Date());
          // -- Send the message --
          Transport.send(msg);
          System.out.println("Message sent to"+to+" OK." );
          return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
      return -1;
      }
     }

     private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username =  "monemail@gmail.com";           // specify your email id here (sender's email id)
        String password = "password";                                      // specify your password here
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
    }

public String getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}


public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}


public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}


public String getSmtpServ() {
    return smtpServ;
}


public void setSmtpServ(String smtpServ) {
    this.smtpServ = smtpServ;
}

 }`
```

sendMail.jsp
         `

```
      </head>
      <body>
      <jsp:useBean id="mail" scope="session" class="jMail.Mail" />
      <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="to" param="to" />
       <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="from"    value="monemail@gmail.com" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="smtpServ" value="monemail@gmail.com" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="subject" param="subject" />
         <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="message" param="message" />

     <%
           String to = mail.getTo();
            int result;
             result = mail.sendMail();
             if(result == 0){
             out.println(" Mail Successfully Sent to "+to);
              }
          else{
          out.println(" Mail NOT Sent to "+to);
                }  
              %>
           </body>
            </html>`
```

Comment: It's not working as in what? You get an exception? You send the email but you don't receive it? You get some kind of other indication of error? What SMTP server are you sending to? Are you allowed to send emails from it? Are you required to do any authentication and if yes are you using the right credentials?

Comment: i am trying to send an email to my gmail address but When i send it   i get an error "Mail not sent to email@gmail.com"

Comment: You did not answer any of the questions I asked you. You evidently need to understand how SMTP works first. What SMTP server are you using? In your code you have a variable called 'smtpServ'. What are you setting this to? "Mail not sent to email@gmail.com" is not the error, that is what you are printing in your JSP. The error is the exception the `Mail` class is throwing and supposedly printing somewhere, where you have `catch (Exception ex)`. It should be in your app server's logs if you are using Tomcat or something.